# page.data.json 404 not found & componentDidMount() not firing in production

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, gatsby, react-highcharts

I have a GatsbyJS site and am hitting an issue where it can't find any page-data files nor is componentDidMount() firing. This only occurs in production, it works just fine locally both with a full build and in `gatsby develop`.

#### Steps to reproduce

Here is a demo page I created for this: https://gwhitworth-dev.azurewebsites.net/blog/2019/06/demo/

#### Things of note

- There is an error that states: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://gwhitworth-dev.azurewebsites.net/page-data/blog/2019/06/demo/page-data.json`
- `componentDidMount()` is not fired in production which it does locally, so ultimately I think this is the issue but have no idea if it's related to the page-data.json

#### Expected result

The chart should render in production as it does locally

#### Actual result

If you open the link above you'll see that there is no highchart rendered although it does render locally.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Hi @gregwhitworth, Do you use the official [Highcharts React](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official) wrapper? Could you reproduce that issue in some online code editor? For example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-dunhx

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here is that Gatsby has an expectation that the JSON content will come in with a mime type of `application/json`:

```
const isJson = contentType && contentType.startsWith(`application/json`)
```

My server was not configured to do this so it was sending json files with a mimetype of `text/html` and this was resulting in the page-data not being loaded and thus the components within the page not being rendered. In order to fix this I added this to the `web.config` file (I'm on Azure, I know this won't be universal):

```
<staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
```